# cv2.addWeighted() does not work

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

path = "/home/jayu/Desktop/openCv/"

imgpath1 = path + "img1.jpg"
imgpath2 = path + "img2.jpg"


img1 = cv2.imread(imgpath1,1)
img2 = cv2.imread(imgpath2,1)
print (img1.shape)
print (img2.shape)


for i in np.linspace(0,1,10):
    alpha = i
    beta = 1-alpha
    output  = cv2.addWeighted(img1,alpha,img2,beta,0)
    cv2.imshow("hello",output)
    time.sleep(0.10)
    if cv2.waitKey(0)==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows(  )
```

when i am trying above code i get error:

```
output  = cv2.addWeighted(img1,alpha,img2,beta,0)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-2TNgni/opencv-3.1.0+dfsg1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:639: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op
```

img1.shape : (183, 275, 3) and 
img2.shape : (640, 960, 3)

what did i wrong here ?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to blend two images of different sizes. You can either:

1. Use two images of the same size
2. Resize one of the image to match the size of another image

   `resize(img2, img2, img1.size())`

   This resizes `img2` to match the size of `img1`
3. Add [paddings](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html) to the smaller image such that it match the size of the larger image.